AllowNoPassword error when i try to log in to server
I followed a lot of videos and they all basically told me to edit the config.default file in the phpMyAdmin folder .as you can see here I changed it to true but now still when I try to log in to phpMyAdmin I get the same AllowNoPassword error.
I changed the value in AllowNoPassword to true but I still get:

Login without a password is forbidden by configuration (see AllowNoPassword)


Please [edit] the question next time when asked for clarification. Do not reply in comments.
